# requestLocationUpdates recalls onPause and onResume infinitely

Tags: android, gps

When i put the below source in onResume

```
locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 15, locationListener);
```

It keeps to recall onPause() and onResume() and then repeat

This appears in android 2.2 but dose not appear in android 4.0

How can i fix it?

I lacked explanation. I already did that the comment below. when GPS turns off on onPause, requestLocationUpdates is revoked on onResume and repeats. I don't know why,,, If there is no removeUpdates on onPause, it runs onPause and returns to onResume and then stops

please help me

Answer (score 1):

In the onPause method (in other words, when the activity is not visible on the screen), we do not want to drain battery so we do not listen for location updates anymore. When the activity becomes visible again, the onResume method is called. for more detial use this link [more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29)

```
locationmanager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

In the onResume method, we request location updates by specifying what is the provider for our locations, the minimum time between notifications in milliseconds, the minimum distance in meters for notifications and finally which LocationListener to use to process new updates

`locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 15, locationListener);`

more info use this link [location listener](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/)

Comment: I lacked explanation. I already did it.
when GPS turns off on onPause, requestLocationUpdates is revoked on onResume and repeats. 
I don't know why,,,
If there is no removeUpdates on onPause, it runs onPause and returns     to onResume and then stops
please help me

Answer (score 0):

For me and those coming after me... it was caused by an extra character that was added into the manifest permission.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATIONx"/>`

was changed to

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

and it fixed it for me.